# sed command usage to replace names with spaces

Tags: sed, rename

I have huge number of files with some names ahead of real filename. Following is the example of the problem:

```
Nora Hmann - sub-01.zip
Nora Hmann - sub-02.zip
Nora Hmann - sub-03.zip
Nora Hmann - sub-04.zip
Nora Hmann - sub-05.zip
Nora Hmann - sub-06.zip
```

Now using sed commnd i want to remove `Nora Hmann -` and just keep `sub-01.zip`. can some one help me with sed command as string to be replaces contains spaces, sed is not doing its properly.

Comment: Spaces are not an issue for `sed`. Please [edit] your question and show us the command you were using. Also, please clarify if all your lines will contain `Nora Hmann - `. Would it be enough to remove that specific string? Can we always remove everything before the first `-`? What will change on the different lines?

Comment: also, can you clarify you want to rename filenames or is this text processing of file contents?

Answer (score 4):

Erasing list of this names to suffix after the last space:

```
sed 's/.* //'
```

But if it is couple of files in directory, it's simpler to use `rename`:

```
rename 's/^.* //' *
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command:

`sed -ie "s/Nora\ Hmann\ \-\ //g" stack`

before:

```
Nora Hmann - sub-01.zip
Nora Hmann - sub-02.zip
Nora Hmann - sub-03.zip
Nora Hmann - sub-04.zip
Nora Hmann - sub-05.zip
Nora Hmann - sub-06.zip
```

after:

```
sub-01.zip
sub-02.zip
sub-03.zip
sub-04.zip
sub-05.zip
sub-06.zip
```

To loop it (I assume you're executed your bash script from the directory, where all files which are going to be modified are located):

```
for i in `ls -w1`
do
 sed -ie "s/Nora\ Hmann\ \-\ //g" /path/to/$i
done
```

Comment: but how to use the command. When tried it says `sed: no input file`

Comment: replace `stack` with the name of the file, which you're about to modify.

Comment: the issue is, when i give batch command `for f in Nora*.zip; do sed command $f; done`; given files names have spaces in between, sed throws away error as it tries to rename files as follows:
`sed -ie "s/Nora\ Hmann\ \-\ //g" Nora`

Comment: ok, if your script indeed is:

for f in `ls -w1 Nora*.zip`
do
 sed -ie "s/Nora\ Hmann\ \-\ //g" $f
done

Comment: Still getting error: `login2.ls5(123)$ for f in *.zip; do sed -ie "s/Nora\ Hmann\ \-\ //g" $f; done
sed: can't read Nora: No such file or directory`

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: Getting following error with your suggested loop:

`for i in `ls -w1 *.zip`
> do
>  sed -ie "s/Nora\ Hmann\ \-\ //g" $i
> done
sed: can't read Nora: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Heinzelmann: No such file or directory
sed: can't read -: No such file or directory`

Comment: ok, go with `find /path/to/files -type f -exec sed -ie "s/Nora\ Hmann\ \-\ //g" {} \;` - single command executed from shell

Comment: the issue with sed command too. Coz when i use it for single file: `Nora Hmann - sub-01.zip  
Nora Hmann - sub-01.zipe`

Comment: the sed command when used for a single file is not givng intended results.

Comment: @Dimitar See [Why not parse ls?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls?s=1|2.2994).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution by using `cut` and `sed`:

```
cat filename.txt | cut -d'-' -f2- |  sed 's/^ //g'
```

Another one only with `cut` (and only in case of the names are composed by first name and surname separated by space):

```
cat filename.txt | cut -d' ' -f4-
```

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` or `ksh`, assuming the files are in the current directory:

```
for name in ./"Nora Hmann - sub-"??.zip; do
  newname="./${name##* }"
  mv -i "$name" "$newname"
done
```

The parameter expansion `${name##* }` will remove everything from `$name` up until (and including) the last space character.

If the name at the start of the filename is not fixed, then the following will grab *all* Zip files and try to rename them in the same manner:

```
for name in ./*.zip; do
  newname="./${name##* }"
  mv -i "$name" "$newname"
done
```

I've opted for using `mv -i` in these examples so that you interactively have to confirm any renaming that would overwrite an already existing file.

Another way to do it would be to simply skip files that would otherwise overwrite existing files:

```
for name in ./*.zip; do
  newname="./${name##* }"
  if [[ ! -e "$newname" ]]; then
    mv "$name" "$newname"
  else
    printf 'Not renaming "%s", new filename exists\n' "$name" >&2
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing the second `-`, another solution is using [`tr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html):

```
x='Nora Hmann - sub-01.zip'
printf '%s\n' "$x" | tr -d 'NoraHmn -'
sub01.zip
```

Note this relies on the fact that the characters in the set 'NoraHmn -' do not intersect with `sub*.zip`.